# Back and forward browser buttons in an app using requireJS and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, angular-routing

I'm using requireJS and AngularJS to write my webapp. It works nicely besides the browser back and forward history. This is how my url looks:

```
.when('/spaces', { ...
```

`<a href="#spaces">` This takes me to the page but the back and forward buttons do nothing. if I change this to  `<a href="#/spaces">` then the back and forward button works but the template won't appear.

I'm using this boilerplate: `https://github.com/fdore/AngularJS-Boilerplate`

Can you take a look at this and try to fix it?

Comment: What browser are you using? What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: I'm using the following boilerplate, which has broken back and forward browser history. https://github.com/fdore/AngularJS-Boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

The back buttons work for me when I try that. Check this HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
angular.module('app',['ngResource']);
angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/index',{
        template: "HELLO {{name}}",
        controller: "IndexCtrl"
    }).when('/about',{
        template: "HELLO {{name}}",
        controller: "AboutCtrl"
    }).otherwise({
      template:'HELLO {{name}}',
      controller: "IndexCtrl"
    })
});    

angular.module('app').controller('IndexCtrl',function($scope){
    console.log("Loading Index");
    $scope.name = "Index";
});
angular.module('app').controller('AboutCtrl',function($scope){
    console.log("Loading About");
    $scope.name = "About";
});
```

When I run this, the navigation works with clicking the links and the forward/backwards buttons.

Comment: I'm using a boilerplate. I need to fix that. Check for the link above. I know that your code works, but i have to have the boilerplate working.